# How to redirect confirmation page after submitting form in Laravel?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `form`.This action is:

```
<form action="{{url('career/save/{id}')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'career'], function () {
    Route::get('apply', ['as' => 'addApplicant', 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@create']);
    Route::post('save', ['as' => 'saveApplicant', 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@store']);
    Route::get('confirmation/{id}', ['as' => 'confirmationMsg', 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@show']);
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $applicant = new Applicant();
    $applicant['name'] = $request->input('name');
    $applicant['sex'] = $request->input('sex');
    $applicant['marital_status'] = $request->input('marital_status');
    $applicant['date_of_birth'] = $request->input('date_of_birth');
    $applicant['email'] = $request->input('email');

    $applicant->save();
    \Session::flash('flash_message','Application has been successfully submitted.');
    return redirect(route('confirmationMsg'));
}
public function show($id)
{
    $applicantData = Applicant::whereId($id)->first();
    return view('applicant.confirmation',compact("applicantData"));
}
```

If every applicant/everyone submit this form then it will create an ID and redirect this in confirmation page with his submitted data.

But after submitted i have got:

> ../public/career/save/%7Bid%7D

I can manually type `../public/career/confirmation/14` and its work perfectly.Now i want after submitting form it will redirect this `../public/career/confirmation/ID`. ***ID*** is dynamic.How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your `store` function, where the actual redirect place.. And, even try `{{url('career/save/'.id}}` in form action

Comment: @NishanthMatha Question updated....

Comment: Its giving an error `Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'`

Comment: the action should be `action="career/save/{id}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `redirect()` right after submission either by:

`return redirect()->to('career/confirmation/'.$id); //pass your dynamic id`

or

`return redirect()->route('confirmationMsg',['id'=>$id]); //pass your dynamic id` .

After your `save()` method, add this line

`$id = $applicant->id;`

and replace

`return redirect(route('confirmationMsg'));`

with

`return redirect()->route('confirmationMsg',['id'=>$id]); //pass your dynamic id` .

Comment: I am getting `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)` this error for your solution.

Comment: Its go to `../public/career/save` route now.But if i add `$id = $applicant->id;` after `$applicant->save();` then its working.

Comment: Yes, you are almost right, code this line `$id = $applicant->id;` after your `save();` method then write my `redirect()->route()....` mentioned line

Answer (score 4):

Provide your post route which you are using for form action i.e. `career/save/{id}`. You can see other correction.

After `$applicant->save();` action, `$applicant->id` should be the last inserted applicant id so use it while `redirect()`.

Further we translate `%7Bid%7D`, it's `{id}`. Means that `id` is cause here.

Try below code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $applicant = new Applicant();
    $applicant['name'] = $request->input('name');
    $applicant['sex'] = $request->input('sex');
    $applicant['marital_status'] = $request->input('marital_status');
    $applicant['date_of_birth'] = $request->input('date_of_birth');
    $applicant['email'] = $request->input('email');

    $applicant->save();

    //Get last inserted applicant id...
    $applicantId = $applicant->id;//Check your correspond table for primary key column label is 'id'.

    \Session::flash('flash_message','Application has been successfully submitted.');
    return redirect(route('confirmationMsg', [id => $applicantId]))
}
```

This should work for you...!

Answer (score 1):

after `$applicant->save();`, get the id
`$id = $applicant->id;`
then redirect, `return redirect(route('confirmationMsg', [id => $id]));`

Comment: Its go to `../public/career/save` route in your way.

Comment: But according to  your route definition `confirmationMsg` should return to your desired page

Answer (score 1):

**Redirection to a specific path :**

```
return redirect('/routepath');
```

**Redirection to the current path :**

```
return redirect()->back();
```